# AsyncIOScheduler weeks работает некорректно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Сегодня обнаружил что AsyncIOScheduler для weeks=1 срабатывает с пятницы на субботу, а не с воскресенья на понедельник.  В чем может быть причина ? Использую python 3.11 и последнюю версию AsyncIOScheduler и все работает на linux. Другие интервалы работают корректно.

Ниже часть рабочего кода. Вроде бы нет возможности принудительно поставить первый день недели - понедельник.

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone=str(tzlocal.get_localzone()))

for strategy in get_strategies(self.config):

    timeframe_digits: int = int(strategy['timeframe'][:-1])
    timeframe_letter: str = strategy['timeframe'][-1]

    add_job = functools.partial(
        scheduler.add_job,
        trigger='interval',
        args=[strategy],
        start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
        timezone='UTC'
    )

    match timeframe_letter:
        case 'm':
            add_job(self.processing_orders,
                    minutes=timeframe_digits, max_instances=1000, replace_existing=True, coalesce=True)
        case 'h':
            add_job(self.processing_orders,
                    hours=timeframe_digits, max_instances=1000, replace_existing=True, coalesce=True)
        case 'd':
            add_job(self.processing_orders,
                    days=timeframe_digits, max_instances=1000, replace_existing=True, coalesce=True)
        case 'w':
            add_job(self.processing_orders,
                    weeks=timeframe_digits, max_instances=1000, replace_existing=True, coalesce=True)
```

Comment: У америкосов неделя начинается с субботы

Comment: Как исправить ?

Comment: @Виктор с воскресения

Answer (score 0):

`trigger='interval'` у вас же написанно, а 01.01.2000 года – это Суббота. Потому и выполняется в ночь на субботу.

Используй триггер `'cron'` добавь время и день недели.

Comment: Так я же указал -  start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00', чтобы он отсюда считал, а не с момента запска. хм.  cron не уверен что подойдет. Точнее пока не понимаю как его аддаптировать под задачу. мне нужно чтобы опредленные процессы запускались с заданным периодом = заданным пользователем таймфреймом (1m, 3m, 1h, 2h, 1d, 3d, etc)

Comment: 3m = "*/3 * * * *" наример

Comment: или выбери понедельник для стартовой даты. 1990 год например